# How do I change to specific sheet via variable name during runtime in OpenPyXl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

So what I want to do is to make a translation program. I want to read the file name of the text-file to translate and then look for a sheet with the same name in my workbook. Example: 
TranslateMe.txt -> Look for sheet name with TranslateMe.txt

Problem is, I can't seem to change the string value of sheet using a real string.

sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(wb.sheetnames[0])

It gives me an error: 'str' object has no attribute 'cell' when I try changing it. I will send my code

I tried changing the value to a string, but it didn't work during runtime...

```
import openpyxl
import glob
import os
import fileinput
import codecs

currentDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) # Sets path to this place


txtFile = "" # The txt-file that is about to be translated.
# I use this string value to try to change sheet value
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Translate.xlsx')

sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(wb.sheetnames[0])

# Define amount of rows and columns in current Sheet
rows = sheet.max_row
columns = sheet.max_column

# Languages: 1 = placeholders, 2 = English, 3 = Greek, 4 = Swedish
language = 2

def FindFilesForTranslation():

    filesToTranslateNames = []
    global txtFile
    global sheet

    for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
        print(file)
        filesToTranslateNames.append(file)
        print(filesToTranslateNames)
        for i in range(len(filesToTranslateNames)):
            print(i)
            txtFile = filesToTranslateNames[i]

            if sheet != filesToTranslateNames[0]: # Underlying problem
                sheet = filesToTranslateNames[i]

            print("TxtFile Name: ", txtFile, "Sheet: ", sheet)
            TranslateFiles()

def TranslateFiles():
    for row in range(1, rows+1):
        for col in range(1, columns+1): 

            # Make sure that col does not exceed the value of language
            if col >= language:
                col = language

            wordToReplace = sheet.cell(row=row, column=col).value # THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR LIES!
            replacerWord = sheet.cell(row=row, column=language).value # same #error over here
```

So whenever I reach the wordToReplace = sheet.cell   code lines, I get the runtime error: 'str' object has no attribute 'cell'

It's important to find the specific name of the file I'm translating, as the sheets won't be in a specific order and cannot be found with a logical for-loop. So how do I change the value of that variable sheet during runtime using the txtFile string???

Sorry for a weird and semi-incoherent post. This is my very first post here on Stackoverflow. Thanks for any help!

EDIT: I just found out that I am changing the string value of sheet during runtime. However, for some reason, " 'str' object has no attribute 'cell' " runtime error

Comment: ***"runtime error: 'str' object has no attribute 'cell'"***: You overwrite `sheet` here: `sheet = filesToTranslateNames[i]`

Comment: So what does this mean specifically? I'm not a very experienced programmer, so correct me if I am wrong: I am turning the string into a non string?

Comment: ***"I am turning the string into a non string"***: You redefine `sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(...` to `sheet = filesToTranslateNames[i]` and later on you want `wordToReplace = sheet.cell(..`. You can't use the same **variable name**, here `sheet`, within the same scope. Read and understand [Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example).

Comment: Ahhhaaaa, now I see! Thank you so much, now I understand. I might just fix the issue. And if I do, I will post it farther down so I answer this question for me and everyone who might be reading it. Also, I will look into that link of yours. Once again, thanks!

Comment: Feel free to post a community wiki answer, checkbox lower right, to show your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question, and in case you made a silly mistake like I did, here was the answer:

```
sheet = filesToTranslateNames[i]
```

should be

```
sheet.active = filesToTranslateNames[i]
```

Thanks for the posted answers, ya'll!

Comment: I didn't think this will work, because you can't set a type `str` to `sheet.active`. To set a `Worksheets` title, you have to use `sheet.title(<new title string>)`.